# Ionic 2 & Ionic 1 work on different Node Versions

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-cli

I was having some major build issues with Ionic 1.7.14 on NodeJS v6. Here you can see the problem and some of the solution that people offered me.

[ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078620/ionic-1-app-does-not-build-ios-ionic-project-has-been-renamed-to-ionic-config)

For the past 6 months I have been working and two Ionic 1 Apps. earlier last month I began to work with Ionic 2. So I installed it via npm.. It all seem well I was working on Ionic 2 apps but did not quite connect the dots as to why all of the sudden I could not build anything on my past **Ionic 1** apps.

***FIRST SOLUTION:***

I re-install Ionic 1.7.14 and I downgraded from Node 6.0 to Node 4.4.4 - voila! It was working once again! **Ionic 1** was building and the CLI understood all my commands.. No more errors.

***THE CONSEQUENCES:***

I had to always make sure I was using Node 4.4.4 whenever I wanted to work on Ionic 1.7.x apps.. I use NVM so a simple `nvm use 4.4.4` would do the trick.
But when I tried to work on Ionic 2 apps I realized that Ionic 2 was no longer installed and there for had to be re-installed, again. So I did..

***RE-OCCURING ISSUE:***

After re-installing Ionic 2, working a bit on that app  then moving on to continue working on my other **Ionic 1** app I realized that when I tried to run `ionic serve` the CLI gave me some errors which led me to believe I did not have **ionic 1** installed.. WTH!? Here we go again.. re-install **Ionic 1** version 1.7.x

Later I tried to `ionic serve` an Ionic 2 app and gulp was not running the build.. It serve the app to the browser but none of my code was being built and implemented into the app. I then realized that the CLI was not running my commands as Ionic 2 but **Ionic 1**.. What now? You guessed it. I had to re-install Ionic 2

***THE CONNECTION between Ionic and Node versions***

So yes, It took me a while to make the connection and I still don't quite understand why this is happening but I've found out that I do not need to repeatedly install Ionic versions as I wish to use them.. I just have to switch between Node Versions instead.

Ionic 2 --> works with Node 6.x
**Ionic 1** --> works with Node 4.4.4

As long as I am using the respective Node Version with each I have no issues. BUT is this practical? Is there something wrong with my installs and file paths? I am curious if anyone has the same issue.

Comment: I'm waiting for answers too for this very critical problem, how does the ionic team think we can build apps with ionic 2 if we cannot maintain our ionic 1 apps?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, not sure if all the steps are necessary.
I've followed these tips:

[https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-nodejs-using- npm](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-nodejs-using-%20npm)
[https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-cli-doesnt-run-gulp-tasks-on-i
onic-serve/49085/6](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-cli-doesnt-run-gulp-tasks-on-i%20onic-serve/49085/6)

> Your system information:
>
> Cordova CLI: 6.3.1 Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1 Gulp local:
>   Local version 3.9.1 Ionic Framework Version: 1.0.0-rc.0 Ionic CLI
>   Version: 2.1.0 Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1 ios-deploy version:
>   1.8.5  ios-sim version: 5.0.8  OS: Mac OS X El Capitan Node Version: v4.4.4 Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a

I think the critical parts are:

1. Edit the gulpfile.js by adding `gulp.task('serve:before', ['default']);`
2. npm install --save-dev gulp-sass@2 (sudo if necessary)
3. downgrade node to v4.4.4 (big question mark about this step)
4. npm --production=false install (sudo if necessary)

Comment: if you bump into shit regarding gulp-sass@2 just do: sudo npm install -save gulp-sass@2 or  sudo npm install -save--dev gulp-sass@2 according to your config

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest ionic CLI and just rename **ionic.project** to **ionic.config.json**... when you 'serve' for the first time, accept suggested installations.

For me it worked right away on the Node 7.7.1,

but with Node 8.1.4 I had to:

```
    1. install Python (add PYTHON env variable)
    ///navigate to ionic 1 project
    2. npm install node-gyp --save 
    3. npm install bcrypt --save 
    4. npm install node-sass --save 
    5. npm rebuild node-sass 
    6. npm install --save @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1
    // ionic serve
```

I hope it helps...