# IONIC does not run platform android command after updating npm

Tags: android, ionic-framework, npm

I added **android** **platform** to my ionic 1 project
To do that i just **wrote** `ionic platform android` 
the result was :

ionic CLI is out of date:

> locally installed version : 1.7.16
>   *latest version : 2.0.0 
>   *https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md 
>   *Run "npm install -g ionic" to update

after updating npm i rewrite the command to add android platform and the result also was :

```
  WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json,
 please rename it. Installed platforms: android 5.1.1 Available platforms:
 amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
 blackberry10 ~3.8.0 
 browser ~4.1.0
 firefoxos ~3.6.3 
 webos ~3.7.0 
 windows ~4.3.1 
 wp8 ~3.8.2 (deprecated)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this new update command by ionic

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Ionic V2.0` there are lot of updates, and they have re-named ionic-based file names. In order to use the update your project and run with new update you have to re-name the files. which means rename your `ionic.project` file name to `ionic.config.json`

more [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078620/ionic-1-app-does-not-build-ios-ionic-project-has-been-renamed-to-ionic-config).

Comment: thank you 
but i just ran my project today and everything got running :) .

Comment: @FouadKajj Happy to help! :)