# Cannot find module ‘gulp’

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework, npm, gulp

When I run the `ionic build android` command, I get the following error:

```
WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
Uh oh! Looks like you're missing a module in your gulpfile:
Cannot find module 'gulp'

Do you need to run `npm install`?
```

I have already tried running this command:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

But I am still getting the same error. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Gulp globally using the following command: `npm install --global gulp-cli`, as described in the [Gulp documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

Comment: Now i am getting    `WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
Uh oh! Looks like you're missing a module in your gulpfile:
Cannot find module 'bower'`

Do you need to run npm install?      I already did   `npm install -g bower` but gives the same error

Comment: What happens if you just type `bower` in a terminal?

Comment: You could try also installing in locally using `npm install bower`, but I don't really see what is causing this issue for you.

Comment: Have you seen this post related to this new error you're seeing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078620/ionic-1-app-does-not-build-ios-ionic-project-has-been-renamed-to-ionic-config

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the following commands:

```
npm install -g gulp
npm install
```