# Ionic platform add android error mac

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

i already have ios i just need the android version but this happen i have android studio on my mac also how can i fix this

```
wWRN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
Caught exception:
 Error: spawn cordova ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9) 

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078620/ionic-1-app-does-not-build-ios-ionic-project-has-been-renamed-to-ionic-config

Comment: Can you run `ionic info` in command line and show us the sysinfo?

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo command to execute the query.